# MVC3 EditorForModel Dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, editorformodel

I am using `@Html.EditorForModel()` in several places, and I was just wondering if there is a simple attribute to specify that something should be a dropdownlist in the view model?  An approximate example of what I am looking for would be...

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DropDown("red", "blue", "green")]
    public string Lasers { get; set; }
}
```

I know there have been similar questions asked, and *I know that I can make a custom template that would implement something like this*... I was wondering if this seemingly simple functionality already existed, or if there was some sort of NuGet package that added this functionality.  This just seems too basic to not exist *somewhere*, and I might have to make a NuGet package myself if there isn't something already.

Thanks in advance everybody!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Follow this link

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/07/31/asp-net-mvc-v2-preview-1-released.aspx

search for "CountryDropDown" on this page to get to the answer

Comment: I guess a custom template for that one field is as good as I can get.  Thanks!

Comment: Terrible answer. This is a q&a site but your "answer" is merely a link to a huge list of ASP.NET MVC features, one of which is the answer. FYI search for "CountryDropDown" on this page to get to the answer